# How create function for dropdown entry like : 2023-2, 2023-1, 2022-2, 2022-1, 2021-2, 2021-1

Tags: javascript, php

Halo all. I have this function :

```
    public function dsYearOfEntry() {
        $t=date("Y");
        $ds = null;
        $ds[""] = array("value"=>"CHOOSE","selected"=>true);
        $t=$t+1;
        for($i=0;$i<30;$i++){
            $ds[$t-$i]=$t-$i;
        }       
        $ds==null? $ds = array("" => "Not Available") : "";
        return $ds;
    }
```

The output on dropdown : 2023, 2022, 2021, 2020 ...

I want the similiar function but the difference is :

- The dropdown entry like this : 2023-2, 2023-1, 2022-2, 2022-1, 2021-2, 2021-1 ...
  so each year repeated twice and each repetition have even and odd end.
- The value that is stored to database should be in 20232, 20231, 20222, 20221, 20212, ... (without "-" hypen mark).

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it :

```
function dsYearOfEntryEx() {
  $t = date("Y");
  $ds = null;
  $ds[""] = array("value" => "CHOOSE", "selected" => true);
  $t = $t + 1;
  for ($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
    for ($j = 2; $j >= 1; $j--) {
      $ds[$t - $i . $j] = $t - $i. '-'.$j;
    }
  }
  $ds == null ? $ds = array("" => "Not Available") : "";
  return $ds;
}
```

Just add a small change

Comment: How about the second idea "The value that is stored to database should be in 20232, 20231, 20222, 20221, 20212, ... (without "-" hypen mark)."

Is that possible?

Comment: `$ds[$t - $i . $j] = $t - $i. '-'.$j;`  ex : `[20232] => 2023-2` ... 
the value submitted from the form will be `20232` ....

Comment: `for ($j = 2; $j >= 1; $j--) `  => `for ($j = 1; $j <= 2; $j++) `

Comment: `$ds[$t - $i . $j] = $t - $i. '-' . ($j%2 ? 'odd' : 'even');`

Comment: Hi sorry let me redo my question 
What if i want to the list shows like this :
2022/2023 Even
2022/2023 Odd
2021/2022 Even
2021/2022 Odd
...
And the value submitted wil be
20222
20221
20212
20211

Comment: you can display the text you want with operator 
 : `https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php